# tuple operation in python 3.5

Tags: tuples, python-3.5

I want to create a new tuple from an given tuple the following way:

1 1

2 3

3 6

4 10

5 15

Both tuples should have the same dimensions(number of elements).
Maybe like this:

old_tuple[0] move to new_tuple[0]

new_tuple[0] + old_tuple[1] move to new_tuple[1]

new_tuple[1] + old_tuple[2] move to new_tuple[2]

new_tuple[2] + old_tuple[3] move to new_tuple[3]

new_tuple[3] + old_tuple[4] move to new_tuple[4]

new_tuple[4] + old_tuple[5] move to new_tuple[5]

an so on...

Comment: I am a little step forward now. I found that I cant do that with tuples, so I have changed the tuples to lists. This link explains me list comprehensions, but I have not got it done yet as I need to access both lists during this operation and I don't know how.  https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it. After I have changed my tuples to lists, I did the following:

```
L2 = [sum(L1[0:n+1]) for n in range(len(L1))]
```